# Compute Euclidean distance between rows of two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, euclidean-distance

I have two pandas dataframes `d1` and `d2` that look like these:

`d1` looks like:

```
  output   value1   value2   value2
    1           100     103      87
    1           201     97.5     88.9
    1           144     54       85
```

`d2` looks like:

```
 output   value1   value2   value2
    0           100     103      87
    0           201     97.5     88.9
    0           144     54       85
    0           100     103      87
    0           201     97.5     88.9
    0           144     54       85
```

The column output has a value of 1 for all rows in d1 and 0 for all rows in d2. It's a grouping variable. I need to find euclidean distance between each rows of d1 and d2 (not within d1 or d2). If `d1` has `m` rows and `d2` has `n` rows, then the distance matrix will have `m` rows and n columns

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By using `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

ary = cdist(d1.iloc[:,1:], d2.iloc[:,1:], metric='euclidean')

pd.DataFrame(ary)
Out[1274]: 
            0           1          2           3           4          5
0    0.000000  101.167485  65.886266    0.000000  101.167485  65.886266
1  101.167485    0.000000  71.808495  101.167485    0.000000  71.808495
2   65.886266   71.808495   0.000000   65.886266   71.808495   0.000000
```