# Calculating a distance matrix in Pandas from a list of xyz coordinates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe of xyz coordinates that looks like this. It is not the full dataframe, only a section

```
             X         Y         Z
0      [-5.43]  [28.077]  [-0.842]
1     [-3.183]  [26.472]   [1.741]
2     [-2.574]  [22.752]    [1.69]
3     [-1.743]  [21.321]   [5.121]
4      [0.413]  [18.212]   [5.392]
5      [0.714]  [15.803]   [8.332]
6      [4.078]  [15.689]  [10.138]
7      [5.192]    [12.2]   [9.065]
8      [4.088]   [12.79]   [5.475]
9      [5.875]  [16.117]   [4.945]
10     [8.514]  [15.909]    [2.22]
11    [12.235]   [15.85]   [2.943]
12    [13.079]  [16.427]  [-0.719]
```

Each row corresponds to a point on an xyz plane, and each column corresponds to that point's position in space. What I would like to do with this data is to create a distance matrix for this data by comparing each point to each other. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Please share the expected output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782104/compute-euclidean-distance-between-rows-of-two-pandas-dataframes/47782154#47782154

Answer (score 1):

First, extract the elements directly from the lists in each cell, rather than use length one lists:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x[0])
```

Now create a cartersian product of your DataFrame:

```
df['key'] = 1
v = df.merge(df, on='key').drop('key', 1)
```

Finally, using `numpy.linalg.norm`:

```
a, b = np.split(v.values, 2, axis=1)
np.linalg.norm(a-b, axis=1)
```

```
array([ 0.        ,  3.78112721,  6.55159408,  9.73626592, 13.05073293,
       16.5094545 , 19.08991902, 21.51870493,
        ...,
        3.80204011, 21.87054435, 19.27190362, 17.05360123, 16.66578891,
       14.17596917, 15.336336  , 14.12221987, 13.25891979, 11.50788799,
        9.1692209 ,  5.45392244,  3.80204011,  0.        ])
```

---

This is a fairly memory intensive solution, because it requires O(N^2) memory to create the cartesian product.  If that becomes an issue, you can create a generator that does the same thing, at the cost of some speed:

```
def lazy_distance(df):
    a = df.values
    for x in a:
        for y in a:
            yield np.linalg.norm(x - y)

In [78]: np.array_equal(np.array(list(lazy_distance(df))), np.linalg.norm(a-b, axis=1))
Out[78]: True
```