# Euclidean distance between two pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scipy

I have two dataframes:

`df1` of the form

```
user_id  | x_coord  | y_coord
 214         -55.2      22.1
 214         -55.2      22.1
 214         -55.2      22.1
...
```

and `df2`, of the same form, but with different users:

```
user_id  | x_coord  | y_coord
 512         -15.2      19.1
 362          65.1      71.4
 989         -84.8      13.7
...
```

The idea is that I want to find the Euclidean distance between the user in `df1` and all the users in `df2`. For this, I need to be able to compute the Euclidean distance between the two dataframes, based on the last two column, in order to find out which are the closest users in the second dataframe to user 214.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782104/compute-euclidean-distance-between-rows-of-two-pandas-dataframes) but it is not what I need, as my two dataframes have equal shapes and I need the distance computed in a per-row manner:

```
Euclidean_Distance_i(row_i_df1, row_i_df2)
```

and save all these distances in a list that is the same length as these dataframes.

Comment: My apologies.  I'm very confused.  Maybe it's me.  Maybe you need a [mcve].

Comment: why you think that dose not work , you just need argmin , with the position ...

Comment: @WeNYoBen well, it returns a matrix instead of a single 2 column array, with userID and distance to user 214. I don't understand how this can be done with argmin. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Qubix I have add that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
def Euclidean_Dist(df1, df2, cols=['x_coord','y_coord']):
    return np.linalg.norm(df1[cols].values - df2[cols].values,
                   axis=1)
```

Test:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[214,214,214],
                'x_coord':[-55.2,-55.2,-55.2],
                'y_coord':[22.1,22.1,22.1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[512, 362, 989],
                    'x_coord':[-15.2, 65.1, -84.8],
                    'y_coord':[19.1, 71.4, 13.7]})

Euclidean_Dist(df1, df2)
```

outputs:

```
array([ 40.11234224, 130.0099227 ,  30.76881538])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I needed.

Comment: this works, however what if df1 has n rows and (lets say) d cols, df2 has m rows and d cols and we want an m x n matrix of euclidean distances between each row in df1 and each row in df2?

Comment: @Aishgadol you would need to [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), similar to how `df1` is broadcast from one row

Answer (score 2):

So in your case

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
ary = distance.cdist(df1.iloc[:,1:], df2.iloc[:,1:], metric='euclidean')

df2.iloc[ary.argmin(1),0]
Out[759]: 
2    989
2    989
2    989
Name: user_id, dtype: int64

df1['close_from_df2']=df2.iloc[ary.argmin(1),0].values
```

Answer (score 1):

We can first get the coordinates as NumPy arrays.

```
x1 = df1.x_coord.values
x2 = df2.x_coord.values

y1 = df1.y_coord.values
y2 = df2.y_coord.values
```

We can then calculate the squared distances,

```
d2 = np.square( x2 - x1 )  + np.square( y2 - y1 ) 

distances = np.sqrt( d2 )
```

The `distances` array is the required distance per row.